# Регулярное выражнение для поиска в DSV строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка:

```
140 "Текст1" 141 "Текст2" 142 "Текст3"
```

Как мне отсюда выбрать текст по определенному id. Допустим `$id = '140';`

Нужно получить

```
$result = 'Текст1';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

как вариант:

```
140\s+\"(.+?)\"
```

тестил на этих скриптах:
http://www.pcre.ru/eval/

Answer (score 1):

Вроде подобрал. Если есть замечания - пишите.

preg_match_all("/(140)+[ ]+"(.*)"/", $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);